# Unable to get psk from network using wpa_cli

Tags: raspberry-pi, wpa-supplicant, wpa-cli

I've build a embedded system using a raspberry pi and a custom linux using buildroot, i'm using wpa_supplicant to manage the Wi-Fi network. Everything works well but i'm having problems to get the stored psk key in the configuration file. when i execute the command to get the psk key the only thing that is returned is an '*'

the wpa_supplicant.conf:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1
#mem_only_psk=0

network={
        ssid="Net1"
        psk="12345678"
        proto=RSN
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        pairwise=CCMP
        pbss=2
        auth_alg=OPEN
}

network={
        ssid="Net2"
        psk="12345678"
        proto=RSN
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        pairwise=CCMP
        auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

what i have tried:

```
# wpa_cli
wpa_cli v2.6
Copyright (c) 2004-2016, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors

This software may be distributed under the terms of the BSD license.
See README for more details.


Selected interface 'wlan0'

Interactive mode

> get_network 0 psk
*
>
```

Comment: Guess: It hides the PSK from your for security reasons, and replaces it by `*` instead of outputting it. *Why* do you want to retrieve the PSK with `wpa_cli` in the first place? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: yes, you are right i read somewhere  is for security reasons, has i said is an embedded system where i direct boot to one application made in Qt. the application manages the wifi network so I pick the wpa_cli source code and implement only what i need in my qt/c++ application. I want to know the psk stored in the wpa_supplicant file to display it if the autenticated user wants to.

Comment: i don't understand why root cannot have the psk key, i can always open the wpa_supplicant conf file e search for the psk.

Comment: Probably because wpa_cli might be run setuid root, or allowed sudo root, to allow ordinary users to connect to WLAN. But that doesn't mean ordinary users should be able to see the PSK. But if you really want to know, you'll have to email the author.